No bean of type [io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer] exists
I have this working in test code for a minimal application, but for some reason the build for a library is failing:
fun run(applicationProperties: Map<String, Any> = emptyMap()): ApplicationContext {
    val applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run(applicationProperties)
    embeddedServer = applicationContext.getBean(EmbeddedServer::class.java)
    return applicationContext
}

I've added the runtime and kotlin-runtime to the test dependencies.   I added an application.yml.   I can make some progress by commenting out the embeddedServer, but I'd like to put this into a textFixture and use it across all my builds.   I must be missing a requirement for instantiating the EmbeddedServer but I'm not sure what.   The only difference seems to be the plugin io.micronaut.minimal.application versus io.micronaut.minimal.library.
https://github.com/waveskimmer/micronaut-embedded-server

There's too little information in your question for us to solve this. Please go to https://micronaut.io/launch, create a new application, and compare the generated code with what you have. BR

@RoarS.  I wrote a trivial library that demonstrates the issue:   https://github.com/waveskimmer/micronaut-embedded-server

The value of Micronaut.runtime is ignored by the plugin io.micronaut.minimal.library and by io.micronaut.library as well.
You should add
testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty")

to make your test work.
